# what structure should I follow to log exception in a text file in json format? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to log excretions in a text file in JSON format. Whole file is like a JSON object (an array of customeModle Class).

It works fine for first time but for next time when I go to log into the file I have to read it then add the new object into the array then delete previous and save it again and obviously it is not a good way to log errors.

**Problems**

1. Suppose there are many errors are getting logged at a single point of time and all are reading and appending the array then writing it back to the log file then many error won't be logged for sure.
2. It is consuming and wasting to much cpu and ram energy.

Please suggest a way to append new objects in the existing file without overwriting it.

Many thanks for your help you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/), you can open a file (**output stream**) in append mode.

Given you hold a reference to file output stream `outStream`, you can use below method to append data:

```
[NSJsonSerialization writeJSONObject:myNewObject toStream:outStream options:1 error:&error]
```

However, I would personally use the option you are already doing - read the data in mutable object, modify and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert it back to data again. Finally, save that data to disk - replacing the original. As this keeps JSON structure intact.

Comment: I have updated the question and mentioned why can not I go with the current way and secondly appending the log file is breaking the JSON

Comment: Writing in append mode is always risky. Why don't you optimize your code by saving the data locally and then write to file after a trigger - just before you need that file to post to server. This is kind of lazy loading. Saving data locally in `NSDictionary` won't consume much of memory.